# How to use Beyond Compare 3 with Atom and difftool command?

Tags: git, atom-editor, beyondcompare

I am using Atom with the package: **git-plus**.

I've configured BC as the diff tool like so (from the official BC site):

[image]

And indeed, in the windows command prompt, when typing "git difftool" the BC gui opens fine.

But inside Atom, when pressing Ctrl+Shift+H and choosing:
[image]

I get an error: 
"**You dont have a Git tool configured**"

What configuration is missing in git-plus package for this to work?